# Turn a list of weird nested dictionary into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance, dictionary

I have a weird list that nests some dictionaries in it that looks something like this:

```
lst = [{"uniqueid": "100","Content":[{"SaleNum":"1","Date":"12","Price":"230"}, {"SaleNum":"2","Date":"13","Price":"234"}, {"SaleNum":"3","Date":"14","Price":"382"}]}, 
       {"uniqueid": "101","Content":[{"SaleNum":"1","Date":"25","Price":"382"}, {"SaleNum":"2","Date":"26","Price":"493"}, {"SaleNum":"3","Date":"28","Price":"384"}]},
       {"uniqueid": "102","Content":[{"SaleNum":"1","Date":"25","Price":"334"}, {"SaleNum":"2","Date":"26","Price":"273"}, {"SaleNum":"3","Date":"28","Price":"394"}]}]
```

I want to convert this into a table of the form

| uniqueid | salenum | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 12 | 230 |
| 100 | 2 | 13 | 234 |
| 100 | 3 | 14 | 382 |
| 101 | 1 | 25 | 382 |
| 101 | 2 | 26 | 493 |
| 101 | 3 | 28 | 384 |
| 102 | 1 | 25 | 334 |
| 102 | 2 | 26 | 273 |
| 102 | 3 | 28 | 394 |

One of the problem is that the data may be very big as there are > 1 million unique ids so I want to ask for ways that can efficiently transform the list into a data frame in Python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst).explode('Content', ignore_index=True)
        .pipe(lambda d: d.join(pd.json_normalize(d.pop('Content'))))
      )
```

Or with the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and a list comprehension:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([d|d2 for d in lst for d2 in d['Content']])
        .drop(columns='Content')
     )

# or if you only have uniqueid as external key
df = pd.DataFrame([{'uniqueid': d['uniqueid']}|d2
                   for d in lst for d2 in d['Content']])
```

Output:

```
  uniqueid SaleNum Date Price
0      100       1   12   230
1      100       2   13   234
2      100       3   14   382
3      101       1   25   382
4      101       2   26   493
5      101       3   28   384
6      102       1   25   334
7      102       2   26   273
8      102       3   28   394
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    ss1=pd.Series(ss.Content)
    return pd.concat([ss[["uniqueid"]],ss1])

pd.DataFrame(lst).explode("Content").apply(function1,1)
```

out：

```
 SaleNum Date Price uniqueid
0       1   12   230      100
0       2   13   234      100
0       3   14   382      100
1       1   25   382      101
1       2   26   493      101
1       3   28   384      101
2       1   25   334      102
2       2   26   273      102
2       3   28   394      102
```